# how to fetch specific user info based on pages codeigniter MVC

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter's MVC and I am building an app where users can create their own pages where they get to write about their hobbies ( cars, books and movies) for other people to read.

When you go on a user's page, you should be able to see their topics ( writing about cars for example).

I am having trouble fetching the data for each page, from the mysql table. I have a good understanding of codeigniter's MVC when passing user id to a function from the view page (using a button) to the model page.

However, I dont know how to load data of a page based on a user's id.

Any examples of the MVC structure would be much appreciated.

Here is what I mean in the picture below

[image]

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your VIEW file, in **href**, pass the created_page_id like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>controller/function/<?php echo $value_of_created_page_id?>"></a>
```

Now in the controller, your function should be something like

```
function function_name()
{
   $created_page_id = $this->uri->segment(3); //this is how you get the id
   if($created_page_id != '')
      {
          // pass page_data to your view page now using query.
          //do some extra things if needed.
          $page_data['view_result'] = $this->Your_Model_Name->your_model_function_name();
          $this->load->view('your_page_name',$page_data);
      }
   else
      {
          redirect(base_url(),'refresh');
      }
}
```

Now in view page, show data from the variable passed name $view_result;

Comment: thanks! this is excellent work! for the models function do i just pass $created_page_id to the model function to gather the the $created_page_id details? This is what I am thinking .... 
 public function your_model_function_name($created_page_id) {
  
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE `created_page_id` = '" . $created_page_id . "' ");
  return $query->result_array();
  
 }

Comment: Great! thanks alot for your help @shuvro. May I ask if you have any good articles to read on this topic? if not that's fine :) Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome. BUT No. These things are actually built up technically while working. But this is the easiest rule to do these type of things in codeigniter :) But you should know about uri segment. Read that from codeigniter ellislab documentation. :)

Comment: You're absolutely right, its all built from practice. Thanks for your help man and you have a wonderful week!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need a join?
$this->db->join()
[[docs]](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)